# What is a good word to mean "nostalgia for the future"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Especially when "nostalgia" is presented in terms of "a longing for the past" and "evoking fond memories." For example, a word which would mean "a fondness for the present or future."

A contextual sentence might be:

> He never seemed to dwell on past times—good or bad—and had countdown calendars around his house for nearly every holiday imaginable. When making conversation with him, you could always sense an excited anticipation in his words. He claimed that it was an intense feeling of ___ which drove him to look forward so enthusiastically.

Comment: Instead of just asking for an antonym, can you define what this word should mean in a positive sense? There are many ways words can be "antonyms": for example, do you want a word that means "a longing for the future" or "a lack of longing for the past" or "a distaste for the past"? It would also help if you added an example sentence showing how you would like to use this word.

Comment: We all know what nostalgia means.  If you want an "antonym," you are going to have to say what you mean by "antonym."  "Nostalgia" has no obvious antonyms.  Nostalgia can be both pleasant and unpleasant, so that isn't categorical.  Are you asking for the name of an emotion that makes you hate this past?  Are asking for the name of something that embodies hating the present?  Or enjoying the present? Are you asking for the name of having bad memories evoked?  The possibilities for antonyms are not clear.  Nostalgia is enjoyed by some and hated by others.

Comment: "forward-looking", "unromantic", "practical"

Comment: In some ways one might say that ***hopeful*** might work.

Comment: Going by your example, I think the concern person is **optimistic**! He claimed that it was an intense feeling of **optimism** which drove him to look forward so enthusiastically. However, this is in no way an antonym of nostalgia.

Comment: Hi, Just a heads-up. Your question received one close-vote. why not edit your question based on the comments above?

Comment: What's an antonym for "table" or "flower" or "foot"? What is opposite in meaning to such things? Take your pick.

Comment: @Jim, \@BiscuitBoy, ***Please post answers as answers.***

Comment: I recommend _futurephilia_, or _futilia_ for short.

Comment: "nostalgia for the future" makes me think like this: In the 1950's there was a certain vision of the future to be in a year like 2001.  By the 1990's there was a different more concrete vision of the future to be in 2001.  Someone in 1995 with "nostalgia for the future" would cultivate their vision of 2001 to be of the 1950's variety rather than the current 90's norm. But I don't think there is a word describing this thought and it doesn't conform to your example which just makes me think the subject sees the world, especially the future, through "rose colored glasses"

Comment: Related: **Anemoia** - Nostalgia For A Time You've Never Known. Although typically used to refer to the distant past (e.g. before you are born) it can also be used about the future.